# problems with ObjectQuery<t> in Visual Studio 2013 .NET Framework 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, objectquery

I'm doing a POS for a cafeteria in a hospital and I'm watching some videos in youtube of how to do the POS in c# but I got to this part where he uses `ObjectQuery<T>` class and when I declare the instance of the object it gives me this error:

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'Cafeteria_POS_EF4.BVH_POS_DB_MODEL_EF43' to
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'   c:\users\tony's\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\projects\cafeteria_pos_ef4\cafeteria_pos_ef4\cashregister.cs 46  119 Cafeteria_POS_EF4

And this one:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.ObjectQuery(string,
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext)' has some invalid
>   arguments c:\users\tony's\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\cafeteria_pos_ef4\cafeteria_pos_ef4\cashregister.cs 46  49  Cafeteria_POS_EF4

I tried searching on the internet for some solution or something but I only find old tutorials and I cant understand what Microsoft says about how to send the constructor arguments... I'm using .NET framework 4 and Visual Studio 2013.

PS - I want to use `ObjectQuery` because i want to do a `foreach` loop to fill the `TabControl` Dynamically from the items in the database

```
 ObjectQuery<pos_item> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<pos_item>("SELECT VALUE P FROM pos_item AS P WHERE P.pos_item_group = " + i.ToString(), cse);
```

If you guys whant to see the whole class ima post it here below thanks in advance for your time and effort

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cafeteria_POS_EF4
{
    public partial class CashRegister : Form
    {

    private BindingList<pos_item> products = new BindingList<pos_item>();

    private BVH_POS_DB_MODEL_EF43 cse = new BVH_POS_DB_MODEL_EF43();

    public CashRegister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lboxBasket.DataSource = products;
        lboxBasket.DisplayMember = "description";
        //pos_item p = new pos_item() { };
        CreateTabbedPanel();

        FillTabbedPanel();
    }




    private void CreateTabbedPanel()
    {

        foreach(pos_item_group ig in cse.pos_item_group)
        {
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(ig.item_group_id.ToString(), ig.item_group_name);
        }

    }

    private void FillTabbedPanel()
    {

        int i = 1;

        foreach(TabPage tp in tabControl.TabPages)
        {
            ObjectQuery<pos_item> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<pos_item>("SELECT VALUE P FROM pos_item AS P WHERE P.pos_item_group = " + i.ToString(), cse);


            FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();

            flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            foreach (pos_item item in filteredProduct)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = item.description;
                tp.Controls.Add(b);
            }

        tp.Controls.Add(flp);
        i++;

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here in forum that solved my problem.

[The best overloaded method match for XXX has some invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543334/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-xxx-has-some-invalid-arguments)

Still the code will not run because there is an exception ocurring in the `foreach` loop.

The argument types 'POS_DB_MODEL.pos_item_group' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 58.